# Reduce boot times Armbian

Tags: linux, boot

I'm running **Armbian** on **Orange pi plus 2E** and using Virtualhere's **USB Server** to Stream usb ports, i'm running it at startup using **rc.local**.

I need to reduce boot times.
Here is **systemd-analyze blame**

```
1.689s networking.service
759ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
672ms systemd-logind.service
519ms loadcpufreq.service
509ms systemd-modules-load.service
499ms systemd-user-sessions.service
489ms console-setup.service
479ms rc-local.service
419ms keymap.service
399ms kmod-static-nodes.service
359ms cpufrequtils.service
338ms dev-mqueue.mount
319ms systemd-rfkill@rfkill0.service
319ms systemd-remount-fs.service
309ms kbd.service
272ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
249ms systemd-random-seed.service
249ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
219ms systemd-sysctl.service
219ms systemd-update-utmp.service
219ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
109ms udev-finish.service
93ms systemd-udevd.service
79ms sysfsutils.service
73ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
66ms lirc.service
66ms user@0.service
44ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
31ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
10ms tmp.mount
```

What can i disable?

Also what other ways can be used to reduce boot times?

Thanks in advance, Super linux noob.